# CKeditor keeps Old content

Tags: javascript, php, ajax, ckeditor

Trying to update CKeditor content based on dropdown selection and ajax call. So basically i have a dropdown, upon selection the ckeditor changes content. But it doesnt happen all the time and when trying to destroy and create new instance, content remains and doesnt get updated everytime.

Following is the code snippet:

```js
$.ajax({
                            type: 'POST',
                            cache:false,
                            url: '../controller/get_assignment_answer.php',
                            data:{
                                    'assignment': assign1value,
                                    'Load': '1'
                                },
                            success: function(data){
                                response = data.split(":");
                                result_class=response[0];
                                answer=response[1];
                                msg=response[2];
                                CKEDITOR.instances['editor'].updateElement();
                                CKEDITOR.instances['editor'].setData(answer);
                                label.className = result_class;
                                $("#success_msg").show();
                                $('#success_msg').html(msg);
                                $("#success_msg").delay(3200).fadeOut(700);
                            },
                            error: function (xhr, ajaxOptions, thrownError) {
                                var errorMsg = 'Ajax request failed: ' + xhr.statusText;
                                label.className = "text-danger";
                                $("#success_msg").show();
                                $('#success_msg').html(errorMsg);
                                $("#success_msg").delay(3200).fadeOut(700);
                            }
                        });
                    if(typeof CKEDITOR.instances['editor'] != 'undefined') 
                    {
                        CKEDITOR.instances['editor'].destroy();
                    }
                    document.getElementById("editor").style.display='block';
                    document.getElementById("file_upload").style.display='block';
                    document.getElementById("submit_answer").style.display='block';
                    CKEDITOR.replace('editor');
                    CKEDITOR.instances['editor'].updateElement();
                    CKEDITOR.instances['editor'].setData(answer);
```

Why does the editor keep old data even if i am changing the content by setData ?
Is there any caching within CKeditor that i can disable ?

any help is really appreciated

Comment: seriously is it so tough ?